# Aseprite Script Lua "attempt to index a nil value (global 'dlg')

Tags: lua

I'm writing my own Aseprite script from scratch to generate color palettes for me and want to use a drop down list (combobox) to set a flag I can later use when generating the colors. (For right now, writing into the console would be good enough)

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how comboboxes are being used, referencing the documentation:
https://github.com/aseprite/api/blob/main/api/dialog.md#dialogcombobox

My function "is not callable (a nil value)" if written after the drop down list and if the function is written before it, I'm getting a "attempt to index a nil value (global 'dlg') error.

The function in question:

```
local function amountOfColorsChanged()
    if dlg.data.amountOfColors == "7" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 7")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "9" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 9")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "11" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 11")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "13" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 13")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "15" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 15")
    end
end
```

The "combobox" in question:

```
:combobox
{
    id = "amountOfColors",
    option = "15",
    options =
    {
        "7",
        "9",
        "11",
        "13",
        "15"
    },
    onchange = amountOfColorsChanged()
}
```

If I try to initialize the variable to set a default value

```
local dlg.data.amountOfColors = "15"
```

The following "unexpected symbol near '.'"-error comes probably because I can't write dots into variables.

Because I couldn't figure out how to read/modify the data of comboboxes from the documentation, I went and looked for an extension that is using them in a similar way I'm trying to and found this, which is how I got to my approach:

https://github.com/not-surt/Limit-Colour-Component-Levels/blob/main/Limit%20Colour%20Component%20Levels.lua

(It's license permits me to copy and distribute the code freely, if that's in question. However, it should be obvious that I am not)

Here is the entire script for reference.

```
-- Chaonic's Palette Helper

-- INITIALIZE!!!!

local dlg = Dialog
    { 
        title = "Chaonic's Palette Helper"
    }

-- Standard values when opening
if hasvalues ~= nil
then
    hasvalues = true
    local vmhueslider = 160
    local vmsatslider = 40
    local vmvalueslider = 35
    local vmalphaslider = 255
end

function easeInQuad(self, x)
    return x * x
end

function easeInSine(self, x)
    return 1 - cos(nil, x * PI / 2)
end

function lerp()
end

-- TEST DELETE LATER
  local C = app.fgColor
  if(shadingColor ~= nil) then
    C = shadingColor
  end

-- COLOR AMOUNT CHANGED

local function amountOfColorsChanged()
    if dlg.data.amountOfColors == "7" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 7")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "9" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 9")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "11" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 11")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "13" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 13")
    elseif dlg.data.amountOfColors == "15" then
        print("Changed Amount of Colors to 15")
    end
end

-- COLOR VARIABLE STORAGE

local SH1 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.4, -0.6, -0.6)
local SH2 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.333, -0.5, -0.5)
local SH3 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.266, -0.4, -0.4)
local SH4 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.2, -0.3, -0.3)
local SH5 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.133, -0.2, -0.2)
local SH6 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.066, -0.1, -0.1)
local SH5 = colorShift(C, 0, 0, 0, 0)
local SH8 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.066, 0.1, 0.1)
local SH9 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.133, 0.2, 0.2)
local SH10 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3)
local SH11 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.266, 0.4, 0.4)
local SH12 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.333, 0.5, 0.5)
local SH13 = colorShift(C, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6)

-- DIALOG

dlg
:label
{
    id=labelColorsLeft,
    label = "Base Colors",
    text= "Left"
}
:label
{
    id=labelColorsMain,
    text= "Main"
}
:label
{
    id=labelColorsRight,
    text= "Right"
}
:label
{
    id=labelColorsClipboard,
    text= "Clipboard"
}
:shades
{
    id = "mainColors",
    colors = {C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonSetLeft",
    text = "Set",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonSetMain",
    text = "Set",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonSetRight",
    text = "Set",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonSetClipboard",
    text = "Set",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:label
{
    id=labelColorsLeft,
    label = "Amount of:",
    text= "Colors"
}
:label
{
    id=labelColorsLeft,
    text= "Hues"
}
:combobox
{
    id = "amountOfColors",
    option = "15",
    options =
    {
        "7",
        "9",
        "11",
        "13",
        "15"
    },
    onchange = amountOfColorsChanged()
}
:combobox
{
    id = "amountOfHues",
    option = "12",
    options =
    {
        "4",
        "6",
        "8",
        "12",
        "18"
    }
}
-- COLOR CONTROL
-- :separator
-- {
    -- id = "separator",
-- }
-- :slider
-- {
    -- id = "hueslider",
    -- label = "Hue: ",
    -- min = 0,
    -- max = 360,
    -- value = vmhueslider,
    -- onchange = function()
    -- end,
    -- onrelease = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :slider
-- {
    -- id = "satslider",
    -- label = "Sat/Val: ",
    -- min = 0,
    -- max = 100,
    -- value = vmsatslider,
    -- onchange = function()
    -- end,
    -- onrelease = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :slider
-- {
    -- id = "valueslider",
    -- min = 0,
    -- max = 100,
    -- value = vmvalueslider,
    -- onchange = function()
    -- end,
    -- onrelease = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :slider
-- {
    -- id = "alphaeslider",
    -- label = "Alpha: ",
    -- min = 0,
    -- max = 255,
    -- value = vmalphaslider,
    -- onchange = function()
    -- end,
    -- onrelease = function()
    -- end
-- }
:label
{
    id=huelabel,
    label = "Interpolations: ",
    text= "Hue"
}
:label
{
    id=satlabel,
    text= "Saturation"
}
:label
{
    id=vallabel,
    text= "Value"
}
:label
{
    id=alphalabel,
    text= "Alpha"
}
:combobox
{
    id = "hueinterpolation",
    option = "RGB",
    options =
    {
        "Sine",
        "Quad",
        "Cubic",
        "Circ",
        "Linear",
        "RGB"
    }
}
:combobox
{
    id = "satinterpolation",
    option = "Quad",
    options =
    {
        "Sine",
        "Quad",
        "Cubic",
        "Circ",
        "Linear",
        "RGB"
    }
}
:combobox
{
    id = "valinterpolation",
    option = "Quad",
    options =
    {
        "Sine",
        "Quad",
        "Cubic",
        "Circ",
        "Linear",
        "RGB"
    }
}
:combobox
{
    id = "alphainterpolation",
    option = "Quad",
    options =
    {
        "Sine",
        "Quad",
        "Cubic",
        "Circ",
        "Linear",
        "RGB"
    }
}
-- COLOR CONTROL END
:separator
{
    id = "separator",
}
-- SHADE
:shades
{
    id = "paletteShade",
    label = "Shade",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadePalette",
    text = "Generate whole Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- SHADE END
-- SOFT SHADE
:shades
{
    id = "paletteSoftShade",
    label = "Soft Shade",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadePalette",
    text = "Generate whole Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- SOFT SHADE END
-- LIGHT
:shades
{
    id = "paletteLight",
    label = "Light",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadePalette",
    text = "Generate whole Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- LIGHT END
-- SOFT LIGHT
:shades
{
    id = "paletteSoftLight",
    label = "Soft Light",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadePalette",
    text = "Generate whole Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- SOFT LIGHT END
-- SATURATION
:shades
{
    id = "paletteSaturation",
    label = "Saturation",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadePalette",
    text = "Generate whole Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- SATURATION END
-- SOFT SATURATION
:shades
{
    id = "paletteSoftSaturation",
    label = "Soft Sat.",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadePalette",
    text = "Generate whole Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- SOFT SATURATION END
-- SOFT HUE
:shades
{
    id = "paletteSoftHue",
    label = "Soft Hue",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- SOFT HUE END
-- HARD HUE
:shades
{
    id = "paletteHardHue",
    label = "Hard Hue",
    colors = {C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C}
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonShadeLine",
    text = "Copy Line to Palette",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
-- HARD HUE END
:separator
{
    id = "separator",
}
-- :button
-- {
    -- id = "buttonPreset1",
    -- label = "Presets: ",
    -- text = "1",
    -- onclick = function()
        -- vmhueslider = 160
        -- vmsatslider = 40
        -- vmvalueslider = 35
        -- vmalphaslider = 255
        -- reload()
    -- end
-- }
-- :button
-- {
    -- id = "buttonPreset2",
    -- text = "2",
    -- onclick = function()
        -- vmhueslider = 210
        -- vmsatslider = 80
        -- vmvalueslider = 80
        -- vmalphaslider = 255
        -- reload()
    -- end
-- }
-- :button
-- {
    -- id = "buttonPreset3",
    -- text = "3",
    -- onclick = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :button
-- {
    -- id = "buttonPreset4",
    -- text = "4",
    -- onclick = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :button
-- {
    -- id = "buttonPreset5",
    -- text = "5",
    -- onclick = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :button
-- {
    -- id = "buttonPreset6",
    -- text = "6",
    -- onclick = function()
    -- end
-- }
-- :newrow()
:button
{
    id = "buttonGenerate",
    text = "Generate",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonReload",
    text = "Reload",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:button
{
    id = "buttonCancel",
    text = "Cancel",
    onclick = function()
    end
}
:show
{
wait = false
}
```

This is my first post to stack overflow, so I hope I'm doing this right.
Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

While going through the documentation again to check if I have forgotten to mention something, I've seen under https://github.com/aseprite/api/blob/main/api/dialog.md#dialogdata that I need to initialize the use first.

Simply adding these lines to the script make it work:

```
local data = dlg.data
dlg.data = data
```

Comment: The function isn't actually getting executed, but the script loads up!

Comment: What do you think the second line you added does?

Comment: I don't really know what it does, I've copied that part from the API documentation as I've said. From my limited understanding, these lines create a new variable, copy stuff from dlg.data to data and on the second line it copies it back. Logic tells me this is unnecessary, but it works now.

Comment: It works without the second line. I'm very sorry. I can't downvote my own post, otherwise I would do that now.

Comment: I regret now posting any of this.